# Convergence $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} { \frac{\sqrt[n]{n^{p}}}{n\ln{n}} }$

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms

Help please. I need to check the convergence $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} { \frac{\sqrt[n]{n^{p}}}{n\ln{n}} }$$Tried with Leibniz, but can't check monotony.

Comment: The title isn't supposed to replace the first line of your question.

Comment: You need to clarify what is $p.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have

$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^p}}{n\log n}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$$
secondly the series
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{n\log n}$$
is divergent using the integral test hence your series is divergent.

Comment: looks like I could use cauchy condenstation test here again :) ... (+1)

Comment: You don't even need the asymptotics; just use the comparison test and note that you have $\sqrt[n]{n^p} \gt 1$ (for $p\gt 0$ at least; if you're expected to solve for negative $p$ then you'll need slightly more hardware)

Comment: I avoid the condensation test because of my failure last time on it:) @SantoshLinkha

Comment: haha ... happens sometimes :) never mind it (y)